# Dropzone.js - upload folder structures and single files

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm currently using [the structured folder uploader from "nuhil"](https://github.com/nuhil/structured-folder-uploader-dropzonejs) to make the upload of folders/complete folder structures possible with `dropzone.js`.

Uploading folders is working great, no matter how many folders are in the folder, and so on. But when I try to upload a single file, it's not working at all.

Here is the code I used to upload:

```
<?php

session_start();

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = '../uploads/'.$_SESSION['userid'].'/';

if (!is_dir($storeFolder)) {
    mkdir($storeFolder);
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds . $storeFolder . $ds;

    $fullPath = $storeFolder.rtrim($_POST['path'], "/.");
    $folder = substr($fullPath, 0, strrpos($fullPath, "/"));

    if (!is_dir($folder)) {
        $old = umask(0);
        mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
        umask($old);
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $fullPath)) {
        die();
    } else {
        die('e');
    }
}
?>
```

I think I also know what the problem is, as the file I try to upload is always called `undefined` and is not openable, it seems like it tries to make a folder for the single file as well, but as there is none, it just tries to make one with no value (see line `mkdir($folder, 0777, true);`). So I know what the problem is, but I have no Idea how to make it working. Does anybody have an idea, what to do, that single files are working as well?

Comment: I am looking for same answer so far I've haven't found anything

Comment: I am looking for the same answer

Answer (score 2):

Because when you try to upload single file the "file.fullPath" is undefined, You can try file.name then by checking undefined.

```js
this.on("sending", function(file) {
        var name = file.fullPath;
        if (typeof (file.fullPath) === "undefined") {
            name = file.name;
        }
$("#tmp-path").html('<input type="hidden" name="path" value="'+name+'" />')
});
```